# GCP - how to manage multiple application credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, credentials

Suppose I have 5 Google accounts (gmail accounts). Is there a way to create multiple application default credentials (ADC), one for each Google account, and specify which one to use to GCP SDK?

[gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)

> Obtains user access credentials via a web flow and puts them in the well-known location for Application Default Credentials (ADC).

The well-known location is `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`.

AWS has a concept of `profile` and we can specify `--profile` to specify which AWS credential to use. Hence wonder if there is a similar mechanism in GCP.

Comment: Do you mean ADC to run your code with different credentials? (in this case, you should probably use service accounts, since it's not recommended to use user accounts for that) Or do you mean using different credentials for the `gcloud` tool? In this case, the command to authenticate is `gcloud auth login`, and you can create multiple profiles with `gcloud config configurations create`.

Answer (score 1):

You can let the relevant tools know where to look for this ADC file by [setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials).